# Python regex number or whitespace before and after string

Tags: python, regex

I am learning regular expressions and have below question.

I referred the [page](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) and got below information

> \b Matches the empty string, but only at the beginning or end of a
>   word. A word is defined as a sequence of alphanumeric or underscore
>   characters,  so the end of a word is indicated by whitespace or a
>   non-alphanumeric, non-underscore character.  Note that formally, \b is
>   defined as the boundary between a \w and a \W character (or vice
>   versa), or between \w and the beginning/end of the  string, so the
>   precise set of characters deemed to be alphanumeric depends on the
>   values of the UNICODE and LOCALE flags.  For example, r'\bfoo\b'
>   matches 'foo', 'foo.', '(foo)', 'bar foo baz' but not 'foobar' or
>   'foo3'.  Inside a character range, \b represents the backspace
>   character, for compatibility with Python’s string literals.

Code:

```
import re

abc="A \ncat and a rat"+ "\ncan't be friends."
print (abc)
if re.search(r'\bcat\b',abc):
    print ("Found")
else:
    print ("not found")
```

I would like to find all cases where
there has to be either number or white space before and after my string.

So `'1cat4'`, `'cat'`, `'1cat '`, `' cat '`, `'(cat)'` should return positive when I search for `'cat'`.

How should I update my code?

Comment: Why would you want `'cat'` and `'(cat)'` to match? There are no numbers nor whitespace before and after `cat` there.

Comment: Why would you not just check if `'cat' in str_` if you just want to match for if the next contains your special string. It does not seem like there is strict criteria given the '(cat)' example.

Comment: @modesitt This would also find 'concatenate'. Not sure if the OP wants it.

Comment: yeah, neither am I @DYZ. Probably not but ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you want to find any *cat* surrounded by non-alphabethic characters or at the beginning or end of the text:

```
abc="cat. A \ncat and a rat\ncan't be friends, how about 1cat23 and concatenate?"
re.findall(r'(?:[^a-zA-Z]|^)(cat)(?:[^a-zA-Z]|$)',abc)
#['cat', 'cat', 'cat']
```

Here are the contexts of the found *cats*:

```
re.findall(r'(?:[^a-zA-Z]|^)cat(?:[^a-zA-Z]|$)',abc)
#['cat.', '\ncat ', '1cat2']
```

**Unfortunately**, this regex does not recognize herds of *cats* ("catcat", "cat cat", and the like). If this is an issue, you can add more clauses to the regex.